# Intuitive CLT theorem

Tags: probability, statistics

What i've deduced studying some introductory material about probability is that, in layman terms , the CLT states:

> the sum of independent and identically distributed random variables
>   tends to a Gaussian Distribution

Is it correct ?

Answer (score 4):

Even if you want to avoid mentioning the specific conditions (that your distributions have zero mean and defined variance) which are arguably less important for a lay person, the thing that tends to a Gaussian distribution is not quite the sum, it is the sum *divided by the square root of the number of summands*. The plain sum of the distributions will just diverge.

Comment: But the sample total (just the sum, not the average) will approximate a Gaussian distribution (ofc, mean and variance may explode)...

Comment: @user190080, what notion of "approximate" are you thinking of? Certainly you cannot approximate any single distribution.

Comment: I am thinking of a notion of something like this, that for larger $n$, $\sum_{k=0}^nX_k \approx N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$ is a reasonable statement...

Comment: I think if you try to make that $\approx$ precise you'll run into some problems.

Comment: Maybe, I haven't thought it through, but I think it should be possible to give it a less hand-waving meaning.

Comment: I've written wrong. I edit here, please delete your last comment.

" Thanks so much. I have a doubt : from the presence of $\sqrt{n}$ in the denominator can we deduce that, as for large n, $\frac{1}{n}\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, then also the sample average tends to have a normal distribution ?"

Comment: @Qwerto, I'm not sure what you mean by $\frac1n \approx \frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ -- in particular, the sample average just converges to a degenerate distribution at the mean (which you could see as a special kind of normal distribution I guess, but to call that the central limit theorem (rather than the law of large numbers) is silly).

Comment: @Qwerto, I suppose you mean that both $\frac1n$ and $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ tend to $0$? But since we are multiplying by these numbers, what is relevant is not so much their absolute difference $|1/n - 1/\sqrt{n}|$, what is more important is the relative size $(1/n)/(1/\sqrt{n}) = 1/\sqrt{n}$, which is nowhere near to 1 for large $n$.

Comment: In conclusion, does the sample average tend to assume a normal distribution as n grows ?

Comment: @Qwerto, it tends to the degenerate distribution whose value is the mean $\mu$ with probability 1. You could call that a type of normal distribution if you allow normal distributions to have 0 variance, but this fact is emphatically *not* what the central limit theorem tells you, it is the law of large numbers.

Comment: Then, the CLT simply proves that the factor not to make the sum of independent random variables diverge is $\sqrt{n}$ ?

Comment: For it to neither diverge nor converge to a degenerate distribution, yes. (A non-zero constant multiple of the square root of n will of course also work.) But that is fairly easy and not the main content of the CLT: it says that the resulting distribution is *normal*.

Comment: I don't understand why this result is so important. For example the Weak Law of Large Numbers deals with sample average ,that is a very important measure, so i can clearly understand its importance, but this doesn't happens with CLT, i don't understand its theoretical and practical importance

Answer (score 1):

Not completely.

There is an extra condition on [CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT): $$\mathbb EX_1^2<\infty$$or equivalently:$$\mathsf{Var}(X_1)<\infty$$

Here $X_1$ denotes one of the iid random variables that are involved.